# Not able to fetch data using volley's library

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I want to fetch the news from the api but when I am running the app, it is showing the toast message which is inside the ErrorListener block. I don't know what is happening please someone help

```
      val APIurl = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=f2c9d983c1c44dd3a89ab47aacd520cb"

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, APIurl, null,
            {
                val jsonObjectArray = it.getJSONArray("articles")
                val newsList = ArrayList<News>()

                for(i in 0 until jsonObjectArray.length()){
                    val currJsonObject = jsonObjectArray.getJSONObject(i)
                    val news = News(
                        currJsonObject.getString("title"),
                        currJsonObject.getString("author"),
                        currJsonObject.getString("url"),
                        currJsonObject.getString("urlToImage")
                        )
                    newsList.add(news)
                }
                mAdapter.updateList(newsList)
            },
            //While opening the app it is showing this message
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            })

        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest)
```

This is my singleton class

```
class MySingleton(context: Context) {
    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: MySingleton? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context) =
            INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                INSTANCE ?: MySingleton(context).also {
                    INSTANCE = it
                }
            }
    }

    val requestQueue: RequestQueue by lazy {
        // applicationContext is key, it keeps you from leaking the
        // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
        Volley.newRequestQueue(context.applicationContext)
    }
    fun <T> addToRequestQueue(req: Request<T>) {
        requestQueue.add(req)
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than show a `Toast`, log the exception that your lambda is passed, then examine Logcat to look at the stack trace. Also note that Volley seems to be abandoned; you might wish to consider using an actively-maintained solution, such as OkHttp.

Comment: @CommonsWare What can I write in the log message. Please help I am a beginner

Comment: `ErrorListener` gets an `VolleyError`, log or toast it ([HERE](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-use-volley-library-to-parse-json-in-android-kotlin-app) you can find sample how to declare `ErrorListener` with this param)

Comment: ```Recently Newsapi.org has said that free version of api is only available to localhost, if you want to access free (developer key) then host it in your backend service or make own rest api using that key``` I found this on stackoverflow.